# OpenERP 7: how to remove module from installation queue

Tags: odoo

I tried to install a few "Apps" in OpenERP 7 after a fresh db creation. I got an error in the CRM app: it is trying to pass in "Feb 30, 2013" which doesn't exist.

I'm not currently interested in fixing the Feb 30 issue: what is more important to me is to remove the CRM module from the "Apply Scheduled Upgrades" list.

I cannot seem to find the option to "Cancel Install" as I could in 6.x.

Can anyone please direct me to how I can remove a problematic installation from the install queue?

Thanks

Comment: Please take a latest pull of addons it will solve your problem.

Comment: do you mean from openerp admin interface, or do you mean the code (bzr)? If you can provide exact steps that would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: yes from code use bzr pull and than upadate module using -u modulename from terminal.

Comment: The pull for addons folder takes forever. Will have to probably do it overnight. I need this answer in case a module that I develop fails to install. By the way, there is proably another way: go to installed modules and remove the installed filter and go to list view mode. It brings back the 6.x experience.

Comment: OpenERP v7 is not stable yet.so there might be bug related question. so just pull the latest code for server,addons,and web, it might solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to **Setting->Installed Modules** remove **Installed** from search and then write module name to find module.

[image]
Then click on module and then click on **Cancel Install**.

[image]